# Shell not handling escape character spaces

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Recently it seems that shell has changed how it handles spaces in parameters. It used to handle them properly (Or at least as I intended it to), but now it recognises it as a bunch of different parameters and completely misses the escape character.

An example of a small script that used to work very well:

```
#!/bin/sh 
exec /home/evan/.applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text $1
```

So I would give it some filepath with spaces and it used to open the proper file
eg, /home/evan/Document/My\ File\ Path/file.txt would open that file.txt.
Now it opens "My", "File", "Path", and some unknown "file.txt" Obviously, that won't be the file.txt that I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

OS: Ubuntu 13.04 GNOME edition
with latest updates

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the command executes perfect. The parameter does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's why we use quotes.

```
... "$1"
```

Comment: Short answer, but straight to the point. :) I'll throw in this link which explains it more in detail http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments